# Mapping a table with a composite primary key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the following Entity in hibernate, using JPA annotations

```
@Entity
@IdClass(PurchaseCounter.PurchaseCounterPK.class)
@Table(name = "customer_purchases_counter")
public class PurchaseCounter {


    public static class PurchaseCounterPK implements Serializable {

        Integer customerId;
        Integer purchaseId;

        public PurchaseCounterPK(Integer customerId, Integer purchaseId) {
            this.customerId = customerId;
            this.purchaseId = purchaseId;
        }


        public Integer getCustomerId() {
            return customerId;
        }

        public void setCustomerId(Integer customerId) {
            this.customerId = customerId;
        }

        public Integer getPurchaseId() {
            return purchaseId;
        }

        public void setPurchaseId(Integer purchaseId) {
            this.purchaseId = purchaseId;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

            PurchaseCounterPK that = (PurchaseCounterPK) o;

            if (customerId != null ? !customerId.equals(that.customerId) : that.customerId != null) return false;
            if (purchaseId != null ? !purchaseId.equals(that.purchaseId) : that.purchaseId != null) return false;

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            int result = customerId != null ? customerId.hashCode() : 0;
            result = 31 * result + (purchaseId != null ? purchaseId.hashCode() : 0);
            return result;
        }
    }


    Integer customerId;
    Integer purchaseId;
    Integer count = 0;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "customer_id")
    public Integer getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }

    public void setCustomerId(Integer customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "purchase_id")
    public Integer getPurchaseId() {
        return purchaseId;
    }

    public void setPurchaseId(Integer purchaseId) {
        this.purchaseId = purchaseId;
    }

    public Integer getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(Integer count) {
        this.count = count;
    }
}
```

when I do a query using Criteria and using purchaseId and customerId as Restriction.eq filters, that's the query that gets generated:

```
select this_.customerId as customerId137_0_, this_.purchaseId as purchaseId137_0_, this_.count as count137_0_ from customer_purchases_counter this_ where this_.purchaseId=? and this_.customerId=?
```

that of course is wrong because the fields customerId and purchaseId are not renamed to their names that I specified using @Column????

Comment: "multiple primary keys"? Did you mean "a composite primary key"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mapping seems to be correct. This is likely occurrence of [HHH-4256](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-4256) (*Hibernate does not honor @Column(name=...) annotation with IdClass*) . If so, then updating to the newer version of Hibernate offers solution.

Also according bug report using `@Column` annotation in `IdClass` is workaround.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but the @Column specified simply which column to map to your java data.

So you should not apply the @Column annotation to your getters, but rather to your variable declarations themselves.

```
@ID
@Column (name="customer_Id")
Integer customerId;
@ID
@Column (name="purchase_Id")
Integer purchaseId;
```

Comment: It should work on the getters too. You can annotate either the fields or the getters, although you can't use a mix. The normal (and best, IMO) style is to annotate the fields, but i believe the code here should work.

Comment: This code doesn't change anything. The query is still the same.